# When working with BIM 360, what is the best location to add the materials to improve performance?

Tags: textures, revit-api, autodesk-bim360

-Company server
-BIM 360 folder
-Autodesk connector
-or other option centralized in the cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From past trials, the fastest location typically is the BIM360 folder.